# Heading covering up body

Tags: html

I'm attempting to recreate a web page document using steps provided in my book. However, the page I've created doesn't match the example in the book. The heading covers up half of the body of my page for some reason. 
Below is the style sheet I created to try to mimic the example. The picture I provided is of the example in my book. What did I do wrong? book example--

[image]

Here is the code for the html and css:

```css
/* 
   Big J's Deep Dish Pizza style sheet 
   Filename: styles.css

   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     2/10/2017
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit D, Skills Review
 */

/* body and page container */

/* reset styles */

article,
body,
div,
footer,
header,
h1,
h2,
h3 p {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
/* headings */

header {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  position: fixed;
  /* z-index: -1; */
}
header div {
  border: 3px solid red;
  color: white;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto 0.6em;
}
header p {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 6px;
}
header p.phone {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0.4em auto;
  clear: both;
}
.established {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.award {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}
.options {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.pointright {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4em;
  left: 0.4em;
}
.pointleft {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4em;
  right: 0.4em;
}
/* main content */

article {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5em 1em 1em;
}
h3 {
  color: red;
  margin: 1em 0 0.4em;
}
.menu {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
}
.myo {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.list {
  margin: 0 0 0 2em;
}
/* footer section */

footer {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Big J&rsquo;s Deep Dish Pizza</title>
  <!--
         Big J's Deep Dish Pizza main web page
         Filename: index.html
      
         Author:   Justus Self
         Date:     2/10/2017
         HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit D, Skills Review
      -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="modernizr.custom.62074.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div>
        <h1>Big J&rsquo;s Deep Dish Pizza</h1>
        <p>Authentic Chicago-style pies</p>
      </div>
      <p class="established">Established
        <br>1974</p>
      <p class="award">Toronto Times &ldquo;Best Pizza Joint&rdquo;</p>
      <p class="options">Eat in, carry out, or call for delivery</p>
      <p class="phone">(416) 555-3337</p>
      <p class="pointright">&#9755;</p>
      <p class="pointleft">&#9754;</p>
    </header>
    <article>
      <h2>Menu</h2>
      <p class="menu">(prices small/medium/large)</p>
      <h3>Starters</h3>
      <p class="menu">Garlic bread sticks: $5.00</p>
      <p class="menu">Buffalo wings: $6.50</p>
      <p class="menu">House salad: $4.00</p>
      <p class="menu">Caesar salad: $5.50</p>
      <p class="menu">Greek salad: $6.00</p>
      <h3>Deep Dish Pizza</h3>
      <p class="menu">Chicago classic: $15/18/20</p>
      <p class="menu">Meat lover&rsquo;s: $18/22/25</p>
      <p class="menu">Greek: $16/19/22</p>
      <p class="menu">Vegetarian: $15/18/20</p>
      <p class="menu">Make your own (plain cheese): $12/15/18</p>
      <p class="myo">meats: $3/4/5</p>
      <p class="list">sausage, pepperoni, ham, Canadian bacon</p>
      <p class="myo">other toppings: $2/3/4</p>
      <p class="list">mushrooms, onions, green peppers, black olives, fresh tomatoes, extra cheese, garlic, anchovies, fresh spinach, pepperoncini</p>
    </article>
    <footer>
      <p>150 St. Joseph St.</p>
      <p>Toronto, ON M5S 2C3</p>
      <p>(416) 555-3337</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [Looks fine to me?](http://imgur.com/a/GG35C)

Comment: @Jhecht, notice that the picture you sent doesn't look like the book example. The picture you sent is what my code creates. The picture I uploaded is what it should look like.

Comment: how doesn't it look like the example??

Comment: Because the title is covering up the body. You can't see where it says "menu"

Comment: It's because the header has is set to be `position:fixed`, you can change the z-index of your menu element and it should pop up on top, but you'll lose the text.

Comment: But the picture I uploaded is what it's supposed to look like. Is there a way to fix it to look like the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping this is what you're referring to. The problems were a couple of things, but the biggest was that there was some strange usage of `position:fixed` and `position:absolute`. This looks like the screenshot you gave us (i.e. you can see the "menu" portion), but how it will go with the rest of your book, unfortunately, I do not know.

```css
/* 
   Big J's Deep Dish Pizza style sheet 
   Filename: styles.css

   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     2/10/2017
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit D, Skills Review
 */

/* body and page container */

/* reset styles */

article,
body,
div,
footer,
header,
h1,
h2,
h3 p {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
/* headings */

header {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: -1  */ 
}
header div {
  border: 3px solid red;
  color: white;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto 0.6em;
}
header p {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 6px;
}
header p.phone {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0.4em auto;
  clear: both;
}
.established {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.award {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}
.options {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.pointright {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4em;
  left: 0.4em;
}
.pointleft {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4em;
  right: 0.4em;
}
/* main content */

article {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5em 1em 1em;
}
h3 {
  color: red;
  margin: 1em 0 0.4em;
}
.menu {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
}
.myo {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.list {
  margin: 0 0 0 2em;
}
/* footer section */

footer {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Big J&rsquo;s Deep Dish Pizza</title>
  <!--
         Big J's Deep Dish Pizza main web page
         Filename: index.html
      
         Author:   Justus Self
         Date:     2/10/2017
         HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit D, Skills Review
      -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="modernizr.custom.62074.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div>
        <h1>Big J&rsquo;s Deep Dish Pizza</h1>
        <p>Authentic Chicago-style pies</p>
      </div>
      <p class="established">Established
        <br>1974</p>
      <p class="award">Toronto Times &ldquo;Best Pizza Joint&rdquo;</p>
      <p class="options">Eat in, carry out, or call for delivery</p>
      <p class="phone">(416) 555-3337</p>
      <p class="pointright">&#9755;</p>
      <p class="pointleft">&#9754;</p>
    </header>
    <article>
      <h2>Menu</h2>
      <p class="menu">(prices small/medium/large)</p>
      <h3>Starters</h3>
      <p class="menu">Garlic bread sticks: $5.00</p>
      <p class="menu">Buffalo wings: $6.50</p>
      <p class="menu">House salad: $4.00</p>
      <p class="menu">Caesar salad: $5.50</p>
      <p class="menu">Greek salad: $6.00</p>
      <h3>Deep Dish Pizza</h3>
      <p class="menu">Chicago classic: $15/18/20</p>
      <p class="menu">Meat lover&rsquo;s: $18/22/25</p>
      <p class="menu">Greek: $16/19/22</p>
      <p class="menu">Vegetarian: $15/18/20</p>
      <p class="menu">Make your own (plain cheese): $12/15/18</p>
      <p class="myo">meats: $3/4/5</p>
      <p class="list">sausage, pepperoni, ham, Canadian bacon</p>
      <p class="myo">other toppings: $2/3/4</p>
      <p class="list">mushrooms, onions, green peppers, black olives, fresh tomatoes, extra cheese, garlic, anchovies, fresh spinach, pepperoncini</p>
    </article>
    <footer>
      <p>150 St. Joseph St.</p>
      <p>Toronto, ON M5S 2C3</p>
      <p>(416) 555-3337</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's actually exactly what I needed, thanks so much. Do you know how to make that "options" element be on the same line as the "established" and "Best pizza joint" elements?

Comment: I can, but glancing through the CSS I would change quite a bit about what was there since it honestly just seems a hot mess.

Comment: Yeah. I have a feeling I messed this whole project up big time. But oh well. Thanks for the help Jhecht.

Comment: It's okay to mess up -- you're learning! Trust me I messed up _plenty_ of things (hell, I still do). Just remember failing is just the precursor to success.

Answer (score -1):

```css
/* 
   Big J's Deep Dish Pizza style sheet 
   Filename: styles.css

   Author:   name
   Date:     date
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit D, Skills Review
 */

/* body and page container */

/* reset styles */

article, body, div, footer, header, h1, h2, h3, p {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  
}
/* headings */

header {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  position: relative;
  /* z-index: -1; */
}
header div {
  border: 3px solid red;
  color: white;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto 0.6em auto;
}
header p {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 6px;
}
header p.phone {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 3px solid red;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0.4em auto 0.4em auto;
  clear: both;
}
.established {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.options {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.award {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}
.pointright {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4em;
  left: 0.4em;
}
.pointleft {
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4em;
  right: 0.4em;
}
/* main content */

article {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5em 1em 1em 1em;
}
article p {
   margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
h3 {
  color: red;
  margin: 1em 0 0.4em 0;
}
.myo {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.list {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
/* footer section */

footer {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Big J&rsquo;s Deep Dish Pizza</title>
      <!--
         Big J's Deep Dish Pizza main web page
         Filename: index.html
      
         Author:   name
         Date:     date
         HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit D, Skills Review
      -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="modernizr.custom.62074.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <header>
            <div>
               <h1>Big J&rsquo;s Deep Dish Pizza</h1>
               <p>Authentic Chicago-style pies</p>
            </div>
            <p class="established">Established<br>1974</p>
            <p class="award">Toronto Times &ldquo;Best Pizza Joint&rdquo;</p>
            <p class="options">Eat in, carry out, or call for delivery</p>
            <p class="phone">(416) 555-3337</p>
            <p class="pointright"> &#9755;> </p>
            <p class="pointleft"> &#9754;> </p>
         </header>
         <article>
            <h2>Menu</h2>
            <p>(prices small/medium/large)</p>
            <h3>Starters</h3>
            <p>Garlic bread sticks:  $5.00</p>
            <p>Buffalo wings:  $6.50</p>
            <p>House salad: $4.00</p>
            <p>Caesar salad: $5.50</p>
            <p>Greek salad: $6.00</p>
            <h3>Deep Dish Pizza</h3>
            <p>Chicago classic: $15/18/20</p>
            <p>Meat lover&rsquo;s: $18/22/25</p>
            <p>Greek: $16/19/22</p>
            <p>Vegetarian: $15/18/20</p>
            <p>Make your own (plain cheese): $12/15/18</p>
            <p class="myo">meats: $3/4/5</p>
            <p class="list">sausage, pepperoni, ham, Canadian bacon</p>
            <p class="myo">other toppings: $2/3/4</p>
            <p class="list">mushrooms, onions, green peppers, black olives, fresh tomatoes, extra cheese, garlic, anchovies, fresh spinach, pepperoncini</p>
         </article>
         <footer>
            <p>150 St. Joseph St.</p>
            <p>Toronto, ON M5S 2C3</p>
            <p>(416) 555-3337</p>
         </footer>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```